# Make [windows-registry] a synonym of [registry] or vice versa

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[registry](/questions/tagged/registry) currently has the following wiki entry:

> Windows registry is a place to save the configuration for hardware, software and the operating system (Windows). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry

so it's supposing that all the posts using it (1229 at the time of writing) are related to the Windows Registry.

At the same time, [windows-registry](/questions/tagged/windows-registry) is seeing wide usage (445 posts).

So let's make one a synonym of the other.

Comment: Propose [tag:registry] as a tag synonym for [tag:windows-registry] (not the other way around) and I'll vote for it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Don't object, I've updated my answer's title

Comment: Fine.  However, you have not actually submitted registry as a tag synonym suggestion for windows-registry at the link above.  I see that you do not have 5 votes in the [tag:windows-registry] tag yet.  Why don't you retag a few of your [tag:registry] answers to  [tag:windows-registry], so that you will be able to suggest a synonym?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Great idea! Done. I thoutgh that I have to have 5 votes in `registry` to suggest a synonym to it, but actually have to have in `windows-reistry` to suggest it as a synonym!

Comment: Interesting; I too thought it worked the other way.  Do you realize that by suggesting `windows-registry` as a synonym for `registry`, rather than the other way around, you are going against the desire of the people voting below?  If that synonym is approved, then all posts currently tagged `windows-registry` will be re-tagged `registry`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I voted below too. Anyway it can be swapped later, I'll take care about that.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure.  What do you mean it can be swapped later?  I don't think it can.  If you look at tag [tag:mathematica] you will see that it has a synonym `wri-mathematica` -- this resulted from someone's attempt to change the tag to the more specific form, but he did not understand how the tag synonyms work, and therefore proposed the synonyms in reverse, as you just did.  Now, any post tagged `wri-mathematica` is automatically retagged `mathematca` which is exactly the opposite of what he desired.  (BTW, that someone was not me; I am not just speaking in third person for effect.)

Answer (score 12):

I'd rather delete `registry` at all in favour of `windows-registry` for clarity.